# OpenGL style stack library for as3

Tags: actionscript-3, api, opengl, graphics, 3d

I am currently working on a 3D engine in AS3, I have designed it for the new upcoming Molehill API but I also want to render to the current AS3 graphics API. I thought that I would write a stack based implementation to render to the target DisplayObject. I then realised that I could essentially create an OpenGL API style interface to abstract my 3D engine from the actual rasterizing processes. (Just like any 3D engine built on OpenGL) This would also then allow other 3D engines to make use of the code as with any other imported library. Obviously there would be functionality handling the viewport, matrix stack etc, but a simple example my be:

```
AS3GL.begin( AS3GL.GL_TRIANGLES );

AS3GL.color3f(1,0,0);
AS3GL.vertex2f(0,0);

AS3GL.color3f(0,1,0);
AS3GL.vertex2f(.5,0);

AS3GL.color3f(0,0,1);
AS3GL.vertex2f(.5,.5);

AS3GL.end();
```

I wondered if anything like this already exists for AS3 that I could use, or if anyone has any detailed information about the inner state systems and/or stack implementations of OpenGL.

Comment: This is a good question. I haven't seen this implemented, but it's something I've thought about doing in the past. Going to think about this... I might come back with an answer...

Comment: So you want to recreate immediate mode with these functions called every frame, no display lists, no vertex buffers? OpenGl has already scrapped that approach, but maybe you target the most simple-for-programmer model, with no extra setup.

Comment: The closest thing to that I've seen seems to be Yogurt3D ( http://drawlogic.com/2009/04/30/flash-3d-engine-yogurt3d-based-on-opengl/ ). The site is down for now, but I remember seeing some impressive demos before.

Comment: @alex, I'm thinking about this from my own practical usage point of view. I just created a Molehill 3D engine and I want to reuse the renderer code to deliver commands to the rasterizer API in the same way / similar to the way we deliver data to Molehill. But I see your point about immediate mode, I assume you're talking about programmable vertex shaders etc

Comment: @George I think Yogurt3D actually analyzes existing C code with OpenGL instructions and migrates it to Flash, this isn't really the approach I'm talking about, I'm just thinking about the same abstraction that is between the current GPU APIs and the Flash app itself but still written in Flash.

Comment: @alex Just a note about state based renderers, correct me if I'm wrong but don't many engines use a combination of shaders and states and use immediate mode to apply the states such as alpha, culling, wireframe state etc?

Comment: You're emulating OpenGL immediate mode there. You should know, that immediate mode is now considered deprecated and should not be used in new developments for a number of reasons: For one the overhead of function calls kills performance. But also batching the data allows for certain cache optimizations. And not to forget that passing the data in arrays allows to store it on GPU memory using VBOs. On a side note: Your project sounds like Papervision3D to me.

Comment: Papervision includes many other things such as a screnegraph, io, bounding volumes, collision checking etc etc...Whilst papervision also rasterizes the scene, this is all about delivering data to be rasterized with an OpenGL style API. Data can be provided to this system as a VertexBuffer and IndexBuffer along with shader programs as a pixelbender pbj etc and the equivalent of a VBO, PBO & FBO etc will be simulated within as3. Some of your points are correct, but since this is not aimed for Molehill, GPU caches etc will also need to be simulated, i.e. cached in flash memory.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Mole here. What you want to do is very possible. You should start with reading old OpenGL specs. However please consider what you really want to do and why. As an educational exercise it is great to map tech from the 70s to a modern API. If you want to do a useful library or learn modern 3d, this is a dead end. One great thing about the Molehill API is that it does the right balance between a scripting language and GPUs: Use script to batch big chunks of triangle drawing. Doing multiple calls for every single vertex defeats that model.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to start this as a project myself, if anyone wishes to contribute please contact me. I have registered the site [AS3GL.com](http://as3gl.com) and setup a google code repo ready for this. If anyone is able to send info about the stacks and inner workings of OpenGL, I would appreciate any info.

[EDIT]

This library became discontinued, but here is the GitHub repo for reference 'dev branch' https://github.com/Zest3D/as3gl/tree/dev

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is OpenGL reference. Speaking of implementations, there are many of them. One open source is Mesa3d.